# How Configure Devart dotConnect for SQLite Code First?

Tags: c#, sqlite

Can anyone configure the following sample code ?
When I run the following code, I get the error :

> No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with
>   invariant name 'Devart.Data.SQLite'

**Setting in Machine.config**

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="dotConnect for SQLite" invariant="Devart.Data.SQLite"
        description="Devart dotConnect for SQLite" type="Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteProviderFactory, Devart.Data.SQLite, Version=4.6.287.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

after add below block code in app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Devart.Data.SQLite" type="Devart.Data.SQLite.Entity.SQLiteEntityProviderServices, Devart.Data.SQLite.Entity, Version=4.6.287.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" >
        <migrationSqlGenerator type="Devart.Data.SQLite.Entity.Migrations.SQLiteEntityMigrationSqlGenerator, Devart.Data.SQLite.Entity, Version=4.6.287.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
      </provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Devart.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="dotConnect for SQLite" invariant="Devart.Data.SQLite" description="Devart dotConnect for SQLite"
       type="Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteProviderFactory, Devart.Data.SQLite, Version=4.6.287.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="myContext" connectionString="Data Source=l:\newDB.db3;Version=3;" providerName="Devart.Data.SQLite" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

following error occurs

> The type initializer for 'EFCodeFirst.MySQLiteContext' threw an
>   exception.

**Download Sample Code :**

[Download](http://www.solidfiles.com/d/cd9615e4fb/)

---

**INFO :**

Devart SQLite Code First (dotConnect for SQLite 4.6.287)

Entity Framework 6

VS 2013 Preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have answered you at [our dotConnect for SQLite forum](http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=27994) .